# Imcrementing a compact monthdate in psql

Tags: date, postgresql, sql-date-functions

I have a compact date string eg '201001' representing  January 2010.,,

for legacy reasons i cannot change the way the date is stored but want a east way to increment the date by a month.  if it were a date type I could use date(compactdate + interval '1 month'), but convering it to type date returns 2020 10 01..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the only solution I found was messy but essentially just used modulo, this is probably because date should not have been in the system in that format especially not as a string

```
select (('201112'::int / 100) + ((('201112'::int % 100) +1) / 12) )*100  + ((('201112'::int % 100) +1) % 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

import time
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

print "Enter Date in (yymm) format"

response_date = raw_input()

new_date = datetime.strptime(response_date, '%Y%m') + relativedelta( months = +1 )

print "new Date",new_date

output:-

turkesh@turkesh-desktop:~/Desktop/py files$ python date2.py

Enter Date in (yy/mm/dd) format

201001

new Date 2010-02-01 00:00:00

turkesh@turkesh-desktop:~/Desktop/py files$

Comment: This is a very simple thing to do in a script, but I was looking for a  Sql solution such that it can be used in views. My solution in the end was to assert that the string date was a numeric and calculate the new date on result and remainder of modulo